# Python Scrapy item.add_xpath error invalid syntax

Tags: python, scrapy

Hello stack overflow friends!

i'm having some trouble with scrapy. It's returning syntax error at the item.add_xpath command.

Here's the script:

```py
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class produto(item):
    titulo = Field()
    preço = Field()
    descrição = Field()


class mercadolivreCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name: "AranhaMeli"
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 50
    }
    download_delay = 1

    allowed_domains = ["https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br", "https://produto.mercadolivre.com.br/"]

    start_urls = "https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/animais/cachorros/"

    rules = (
        # paginação
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r"/_Desde_"),
            follow=true),
        # detalhes dos produtos
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=r"/MLB-"),
            follow=true, callback="parse_items"))

    def parse_items(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(produto(), response=response)
        item.add_xpath("titulo", "//h1/text()")
        item.add_xpath("descrição", "//div[@class="ui-pdp-description__content"]")
        item.add_xpath("preço", "//span[@class= "price-tag-fraction"]")
```

The error returned:

```
item.add_xpath("descrição", "//div[@class="ui-pdp-description__content"]")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `"` by `\`

Your second `item.add_xpath` should be like below:

`item.add_xpath("descrição", "//div[@class=\"ui-pdp-description__content\"]")`

Comment: It worked! But i have a new error now at the line 45 : 

item.add_xpath("preço", "//span[@class= "price-tag-fraction\"]")

Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: double quotes is a reserved character in programming languages so when ever it appeared in your text you should escape them or some how telling your programming language that this character is in my text don't miss with it. you simply do this by putting \ in front of this character as you did in the provided example, you also should do this every time tem.add_xpath("preço", "//span[@class= \"price-tag-fraction\"]")